# Android autofill service does not show pop up on certain app

Tags: android, kotlin, service, autofill

i'm currently trying to implement an Autofill service for my app by following [this tutorial](https://www.androidblog.gs/create-auto-fill-custom-service-android-apps/). It's working on certain app so I can see the popup under the EditText in the login page but in certain apps it's not showing. I've tried with other applications like Bitwarden and 1Password and they are able to make it work.

Here's my code:

```kotlin
val emailFields = arrayListOf<AssistStructure.ViewNode>()
```

```kotlin
     override fun onFillRequest(
            request: FillRequest,
            cancellationSignal: CancellationSignal,
            callback: FillCallback
    ) {
        val context: List<FillContext> = request.fillContexts
        val structure: AssistStructure = context[context.size - 1].structure
        val emailNode = structure.getWindowNodeAt(0).rootViewNode

        checkForUsernameField(emailNode)
        if (emailFields.size > 0) {
            val field = emailFields[0];
            val responseBuilder = FillResponse.Builder()
            val authIntent = Intent(this, AuthenticateActivity::class.java).apply {
                putExtra("emailId", field.autofillId)
            }

            val intentSender: IntentSender = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    this,
                    1001,
                    authIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
            ).intentSender

            val usernamePresentation = RemoteViews(packageName, R.layout.autofill_layout)
            val datasetBuilder = Dataset.Builder(usernamePresentation)
            datasetBuilder.setAuthentication(intentSender)
            datasetBuilder.setValue(field.autofillId!!, AutofillValue.forText("email"));
            responseBuilder.addDataset(datasetBuilder.build())

            callback.onSuccess(responseBuilder.build())
        }
    }
```

```kotlin
     private fun checkForUsernameField(emailNode: AssistStructure.ViewNode) {
        for (i in 0 until emailNode.childCount) {
            if (emailNode.getChildAt(i).className != null) {
                if (emailNode.getChildAt(i).className.contains("EditText")) {
                    val viewId = emailNode.idEntry

                    if (viewId != null
                            && (viewId.contains("email") 
                                    || viewId.contains("username")
                                    || viewId.contains("login")
                                    || viewId.contains("user")
                                    || viewId.contains("user")
                                    || viewId.contains("usr")
                                    || viewId.contains("user name")
                                    || viewId.contains("identifier")
                                    || viewId.contains("id"))) {
                        emailFields.add(emailNode.getChildAt(i))
                        return
                    }
                } else {
                    checkForUsernameField(emailNode.getChildAt(i))
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

What's weird is that the 'callback.onSuccess(responseBuilder.build())' is called even if the popup doesn't show.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
<service
        android:name=".MyAutofillService"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="Custom Autofill Service"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_AUTOFILL_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.autofill.AutofillService" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.autofill"
            android:resource="@xml/service_configuration" />
    </service> use this
```